# Detect UIImage using @2x file

Tags: image, ipad, opengl-es, uiimage, scale

Okay, so I'm making an app for the new iPad with the retina display. Right now, I'm importing images into openGL through a UIImage loader so that I can use @2x images for the new display. I've also made it so that if the iPad has a screen scale factor of 2.0, then it sets the scale of my images to 0.5.

This works fine with the images that have an @2x file, but some of them don't, and they end up half size and out of place. So I want to find a way to detect when UIImage uses an @2x image instead of the original. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I don't want to have to make an @2x file for every image and take up unnecessary space.

Comment: You *could* re-implement `UIImage`’s `imageNamed:` and keep a record of each image. Not sure if there’s a shorter/easier/better way.

Comment: I found an answer for anyone who wants to know. Instead of looking for the filename, UIImage has a property known as 'scale' that has a value of 2.0 if it loads a @2x image, and 1.0 if otherwise.

This should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scale` property of `UIImage`.

From the documentation:

> If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is set to 2.0. If the filename does not include the modifier but is in the PNG or JPEG format and has an associated DPI value, a corresponding scale factor is computed and reflected in this property. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.
>
> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.